# How to implement DSL in groovy way?

Tags: groovy

I  have successfully written apis for converting the below DSL:

```
testCase 
            { 
                name = 'test' 
                params { 
                    name = "var" 
                    value = 'randomValue' 
                } 
}
```

to

```
<testCase name='test'>
     <params name='var' value='randomValue' />
</testCase>
```

This works perfectly. But I want to do this too ( similar to Spock). If user gives this one:

```
testCase 
            { 
                name = 'test' 
                params { 
                    name  |  value 
                       1       |     2 
                       3       |    5 
                } 
}
```

so that this turns into :

```
<testCase name='test'>
     <params name='1' value='2' />
</testCase>

<testCase name='test'>
     <params name='3' value='5' />
</testCase>
```

note that here both name and value can be any string.  How shall I do this? The problem which I face now is I need to create separate testCase when I see a param like this. And testCase can have other embed tags like this:

```
testCase { 
      someTag { 
        someTag2 { 
             params { 
                    name  |  value 
                       1       |     2 
                       3       |    5 
            } 
       } 
}
```

So this to be generated like

```
<testCase>
     <someTag>
        <someTag2>
                   <params name='1' value='2' />
        </someTag2>
     </someTag>
</testCase>

<testCase>
     <someTag>
        <someTag2>
                   <params name='3' value='5' />
        </someTag2>
     </someTag>
</testCase>
```

So in groovy world, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674474/populate-domain-objects-from-tabular-data-in-groovy

Comment: Spock does it with an AST transform https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/groovy-2.3/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/compiler/WhereBlockRewriter.java